# Imagemagick no such file or directory error in Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, imagemagick, carrierwave

I'm using carrierwave to upload images from my rails app, and later pass that image to resque for resizing them in the background. The image gets uploaded properly. The problem  when resque tries to resize it, mini_magick says that "No such file or directory"

This is my ImageController code which handles the upload

```
#create image and embed into story
def create
    img_attr =  params[:image]
    img_attr[:media] = params[:image][:media].first if params[:image][:media].class == Array

    image = Image.new img_attr
    @story.images << image
    if @story.save
        Resque.enqueue(ImageQueue,image.id)
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json {
                render :json => [image.to_jq_upload].to_json
            }
        end
    else
        render :json => [{:error => 'custom_failure'}], :status => 304
    end

end
```

And this is my Resque code

```
class ImageQueue
@queue = :image_queue
def self.perform(image_id)
    image = Image.find image_id
    image.recreate_delayed_versions!
    image.save
end
end
```

And the upload path is set here

```
def store_dir
    "uploads/stories/#{model.viewable_id}/res"
end
```

This is the error stack that I get

```
No such file or directory - /uploads/stories/533d5b8756617390c0070000/res/636a8fe128.jpg
/Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/mini_magick-3.7.0/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:110:in `initialize'
/Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/mini_magick-3.7.0/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:110:in `open'
/Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/mini_magick-3.7.0/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:110:in `open'
/Users/skmvasu/repo/mangoweb/app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:97:in `original_dimensions'
/Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:84:in `block in process!'
/Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:76:in `each'
/Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:76:in `process!'
```

The weird thing is the same code works in my Linux box, and my production box which also runs Linux, but not on my new Mac. Is it a problem with ImageMagick? I'm installing it through Homebrew. I even tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it with source, but that didn't work either.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here? Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: It sounds to me like minimagick is giving you grief, and not imagemagick itself. Would you consider using `Rmagick` instead of minimagick? http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/  Here's a good link: http://blog.paulopoiati.com/2013/01/28/installing-rmagick-in-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-with-homebrew/

I've had much success with rmagick in osx and ubuntu, both on development and production machines. Rmagick is also completely compatible with carrierwave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the error,

```
No such file or directory - /uploads/stories/533d5b8756617390c0070000/res/636a8fe128.jpg
```

Either `636a8fe128.jpg` is not there at the given path i.e., `/uploads/stories/533d5b8756617390c0070000/res` or

`/uploads/stories/533d5b8756617390c0070000/res` one or all of the directories in this path are not there. I would recommend go to terminal and navigate through the path and see if it allows you to change directory till you reach `res` directory. If yes, then inside `res` directory do `ls -l` and see if the output shows `636a8fe128.jpg` file.

**UPDATE**

Specify the full path including **Rails.root**:

```
def store_dir 
  "#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/stories/#{model.viewable_id}/res" 
end
```

without `#{Rails.root}/public/`, path generated was `/uploads/stories/533d5b8756617390c0070000/res/636a8fe128.jpg`  where the first `/` points to the root directory of the server.

Comment: Nope the file exists there. I've verified that.

Comment: Lets discuss this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror as it might require little bit of debugging.

Comment: Actually this didn't work. There was some problem with resque this code was not getting executed.Even with this change, it still throws the same error. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: As per the chat session `Actually that was the issue. I was looking at it in a different file. Thanks a lot. This saved me a lot of time :)` It was resolved. You must have refactored the code. I can't help you without looking the changes. Its always good to post a new question with relevant error and supporting code rather than unaccepting the answer that was accepted.

Comment: I'm sorry. My bad. I'm raising a different questions with my findings.