# Error: "No such file or directory" when uploading image using carriewave

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 4 and Ruby 2. I am trying to upload an image using carrierwave and getting an error "No such file or directory - XYZ.jpg". But when I keep the image inside my app folder it uploads perfectly. Please help me if anybody have any idea about this. Here is my code below:

gem file:
    gem 'carrierwave'

reports_controller.rb

```
    def create
    @site = Site.find(params[:site_id])
    @report = @site.reports.build       
    @report.image = File.new(params[:image])
    @report.save
   end
```

new.html.erb

```
<div>
  <%= file_field_tag :image %>
</div>
```

show.html.erb

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
   <span> My Photo:
    <%= image_tag @report.image_url %></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840422/imagemagick-no-such-file-or-directory-error-in-mac

Comment: If the image is in the root folder of the app the image is getting stored in the publc folder of the app. It is not getting picked up from any other location in the system.

Comment: I guess you should define the folder for hosting external images.
Look into README of [carriewave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)

Comment: How do I define that? Also is this the correct way to assign it in my controller. @report.image = File.new(params[:image])

Answer (score 0):

As you have explained, the reason being not getting picked up from any other location in the system its a 404 Error. I have experienced this on production (Heroku) to be precise and what I did is to change my carrierwave image uploader `store_dir action` to merge the path where images uploaded are stored on Heroku.

**Note** if on production, you can as well find where the pictures are uploaded to before you append your `store_dir action` to that directory and push.

**Example---app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb**

```
  def store_dir
    "public/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

For more Information, see [carrierwave doc on changing storage directory](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#changing-the-storage-directory)